# Can't change "Require password after screen saver begins"

Tags: macos, ventura, lockscreen

In MacOS Ventura, I can't change the "Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off" setting. I'm able to change it in the Administrator account, but not in the regular account that I normally use.

When I try to change it, a dialog pops up asking for the administrator name and password. But when I enter them, the setting is unchanged. It's stuck on "never"; that's the setting I use at home, but I like to change it when I go on a trip and leave the laptop in my hotel room. It doesn't matter which new setting I choose.

I had no problem under Monterey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved with Ventura 13.1 update!

Comment: Upvoting for now, I'll accept after I install the update and confirm.